# How to Initialize Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Float>>?

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I want to operate on a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Float>>`.
This is how I initialize:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Float>> map = new TreeMap<>();
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    map.put(i, new TreeMap<>());
```

but I always get `null` for `entrySet`.
When I try to add an element

```
map.get(i).put(j.getKey(), d);
```

where `i` and `j` are `Map.Entry<Integer, Point3f>`, it does nothing. (`Point3f` is an object from the library `vecmath`)

*Edit:* I changed it to `HashMap` but now I get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure why `entrySet()` seems to be returning `null` for you, but the map initialization appears to be working for me, and looks pretty OK to me.

The problem is in `map.get(i).put(j.getKey(), d);`, for the types of `i` and `j` you stated. You declared `map` to be `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Float>>`, which means `map` has `Integer` keys and `Map<Integer, Float>` values. Thus, when you call `get(i)` with the key `i` being `Map.Entry<Integer, Point3f>`, `map` can't find an entry corresponding to that particular key, so it returns `null`. Then you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call `put` on the map you thought you got.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Float>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Map<Integer,Float>>();

Map<Integer,Float> f =  map.get(5);
f.put(4,5.6f);
```